# Wifi disabled, no hardware switch available, rfkill list reads "Hard Blocked" anyway on an Acer Aspire One

Tags: wireless, acer

Somehow, my nephew (who destroys everything he touches) has managed to disable the wifi on his Acer Aspire One series netbook (Model #ZG5).

It's running 14.04 LTS (32-bit). `rfkill list` indicates it's not soft blocked, but hard blocked.

However, there is no wifi switch on this particular model, and no Fn key shortcut, either. I've scoured the internet... but none of the solutions I've found so far seem to work. Any advice?

I've looked at this question and it doesn't apply to me:

- [Wireless disabled by hardware switch on an Asus X550V](https://askubuntu.com/questions/351594/wireless-disabled-by-hardware-switch)

Comment: This is no duplicate.

Comment: Did you even look at/try any of the solutions?

Comment: yup, sorry. I took a look, tried a couple out. But my main bone of contention here is that my question is clearly not a duplicate of the question being linked to. It makes it impossible to get answers here on this site when people come along and flag or edit willy nilly

Comment: Did you try options asus_nb_wmi wapf=1?

Comment: I must admit to being a bit of linux noob. What am I doing with asus_nb_wmi wapf=1 ? Is this a terminal command? I tried it as a terminal command and got "command not found"

Comment: In chili's answer in that linked question, substitute `echo "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=0"` with `echo "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=1"`.

Comment: Ok, thank you guys. This worked. Apologies to Seth and Chili555. However I still don't see how this question is a duplicate of the above-linked one... even though the answer to the question was ultimately the same. In any event, big shout out to Alaa Ali and Chili555

Comment: Glad it's working.

Comment: Please provide all the tests you have already tried to solve this issue.  If you don't any reader will try to poont you to a question that you may have tried before.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem with the ACER Aspire One of my daughter.
`rfkill list` revealed that Wireless LAN is `Hard blocked`.
Using `sudo rfkill unblock 0` (0 referencing Wireless LAN in above list) solved the issue !

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in acer aspire ES 521

```
You have to blacklist the acer-wmi kernel module:

sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
add blacklist acer_wmi as a new line at the bottom of this file.

then reboot.
```