# Why does putting laptop in suspend mode clear WiFi hard block?

Tags: wireless, suspend

I recently wrote a question regarding my ASUS X551ca laptop which is dual booted with Windows 8.1, and Ubuntu 14.04. The WiFi functions perfectly when in windows, but is hard blocked in Ubuntu. (as confirmed via rfkill list all command). After reviewing many "Ask Ubuntu" posts, I found several that suggested going into suspend mode to clear the hard block, and enable the WiFi connection. After testing this procedure several times, the results confirmed that it worked every time, and is my current start-up work around to enable WiFi.

Although this procedure enables my WiFi, I need to fix the root cause, so I am asking the question: "Why does putting the laptop in suspend mode clear the WiFi hard block?"

Is it the BIOS boot sequence? Do I need to have the network card load first before the Ubuntu hard drive boot disk sector?

If anyone is familiar with this process I look forward to reading your post.

Comment: Have you tried the process here? http://askubuntu.com/questions/351594/wireless-disabled-by-hardware-switch-on-an-asus-x550v/351860#351860