# no wifi after booting until suspend

Tags: wireless, drivers, asus

After installing Ubuntu 14.04 on a laptop no wifi connections were detected.  After suspending then waking the system wifi networks became visible and I was able to connect. On subsequent suspensions the connection stops and restarts again after waking. For now I simply prevent subsequent suspends with power options and the connection, once established, stays stable.

I attempted to use backports following these instructions:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/240616/can-you-install-atheros-ath9k-driver-from-3-2-kernel-into-3-5-kernel

However after doing this wifi did not work at all so I reinstalled Ubuntu. I have also tried a fair few other sets of instructions but they address wifi not working after suspensions not this situation.

According to lspci I have:
 02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

I have been unable to find a driver I can install on this machine.

My lshw log (with wifi on):

```
   *-network
            description: Wireless interface
            product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
            vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
            logical name: wlan0
            version: 01
            serial: 28:e3:47:bc:44:eb
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
            configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.13.0-35- g   generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.100 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
            resources: irq:17 memory:f7d00000-f7d7ffff memory:f7d80000-f7d8ffff
```

Would some adaptation of: [Wireless disabled by hardware switch on an Asus X550V](https://askubuntu.com/questions/351594/wireless-disabled-by-hardware-switch-on-an-asus-x550v) work here? Or Can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: Have you checked wifi drivers?

Comment: Do you mean find an update to: driver=ath9k driverversion=3.13.0-35- g  ? if so, i have looked and I cant find one i can install on ubuntu

Comment: Do you have wifi driver, check in additional driver.

Comment: no additional drivers available

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to minimec on #ubuntu @ irc freenode for this:

The answer was adapted from: [Wireless disabled by hardware switch on an Asus X550V](https://askubuntu.com/questions/351594/wireless-disabled-by-hardware-switch-on-an-asus-x550v)

for the ASUS F551CA the fix is:

```
sudo -i  
echo "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=1" > /etc/modprobe.d/asus.conf   
exit
```

Then reboot or reload the kernel module.