# why rfkill has 2 entries for each of wlan and bluetooth?

Tags: wireless, asus, rfkill

rfkill list all

```
0: asus_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: asus_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

When I hit the hardware button (Fn+F2) the values toggle so the two wlans change

```
from:  no yes; no no  
  to: yes no; yes no
```

Even the "rfkill unblock all" or unblock wlan or unblock  do the same kind of toggling, and can not get them all to  ' no no ; no no '.

Bluetooth works fine, by the toggles (hardware button / choosing system tray / command line rfkill).

```
 # uname -r
 3.16.0-30-generic
 # sudo dmidecode | grep 'System Information' -A2
System Information
    Manufacturer: ASUSTeK Computer Inc.
    Product Name: U32U
```

I managed to get the no, no; no no (phy0; asus_wlan, soft & hard). [no yes; no no : `Fn+F2` -> yes no; yes no : `rfkill unblock wlan` -> no, no; no, no]. Not sure if `sudo modprobe asus_nb_wmi wapf=4` did something.

However, now despite having all four 'no' its still showing 'wifi disabled by hardware switch', and greyed out. Does it have a refresh time when that takes effect ?

I have seen the post "Wireless disabled by hardware switch on an Asus X550V" but that does not provide solution to my problem.

Comment: What is your ASUS model? And please add output of `uname -r` to your question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `sudo dmidecode | grep 'System Information' -A2` terminal command.

Comment: On my dell laptop, I also have 2 devices listed by rfkill for my wifi: phy0 and brcmwl-0. Although only one for bluetooth, hci0

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wireless disabled by hardware switch on an Asus X550V](http://askubuntu.com/questions/351594/wireless-disabled-by-hardware-switch-on-an-asus-x550v)

Comment: On my Acer laptop, the Bluetooth is listed 2 times *acer-bluetooth* and *hci0*. I'm having some issues with the Bluetooth connectivity and I wonder what cause it. Do you think having those two entries in the list might cause it? Is there a way to blacklist one of them and check if it works? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That is because wireless is also controlled also by asus_nb_wmi module.

You can probably fix this wrong behavior by running

```
sudo modprobe asus_nb_wmi wapf=4
```

If it helps, I will add how to make it permanent.