# Bluetooth adapter not being found

Tags: bluetooth, hardware

My internal laptop Bluetooth adapter is not being found by Ubuntu, although it works with Windows.

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series] (rev ff)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 09)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

---

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2232:1029 Silicon Motion WebCam SC-13HDL11939N
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1ea7:1006  
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1ea7:2002  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

---

```
$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes

$ hciconfig -a
$ bluetoothctl 
[bluetooth]# exit
$
```

Comment: Update your post with output of `rfkill list all`.

Comment: Added the output.

Comment: "Hard blocked" means that you have hardware kill-switch on your laptop. Try to find it and switch it on.

Comment: Do you mean the Bluetooth device is switched off? It worked on Windows. And where do I find the kill-switch? The only parts I can directly access are the Wifi Adapter, HDD and RAM.

Comment: OK. So you do not have any kill-switches on laptop. Which model do you have? Please add output of `hciconfig -a` and `bluetoothctl` to the question.

Comment: If you have Asus laptop you can [look this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/351594/66509).

Comment: Sadly, no Asus. It's a Samsung NP350V5C-S08PL, according to the sticker at the bottom

Comment: I have no new ideas. Try to search here or on ubuntuforums for last year and your AR9485.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by unplugging the Bluetooth adapter and plugging it back in again.